# Excel Days 360 function. - Issue with day count in February

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The Excel formula below

```
=DAYS360("1-Jan-2018","31-Jan-2018")
```

returns 30

```
=DAYS360("1-Feb-2018","28-Feb-2018")
```

returns 27

I expected both functions to return 30 days as each month is treated as consisting of 30 days. What I am doing wrong or is there a custom function that can give a result of 30 days in both cases? Thanks.

Comment: The results are correct. Number of days between two dates. Are you trying to get 30 between 1st day and last day of each month regardless of the month?

Comment: @Felix the `=DAYS360()` function returns the number of days between two dates based on a 360-day year (twelve 30-day months), I think OP is trying to figure out why it is behaving more like the `=DAYS()` function, which is the number of days between two dates.

Answer (score 1):

To get the function to return 30 days for February, you just need to use the first day of your first month and the first day of the next month, Eg:

```
    =DAYS360("1-Feb-2018","1-Mar-2018")
    =DAYS360("1-Mar-2018","1-Apr-2018")
    =DAYS360("1-Jun-2018","1-Jul-2018")
```

Those should all return 30.

Comment: I'm in awe that a function returning 30 days for February exists at all.